# Azure SQL - DTU CPU usage disparity

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, connection-pooling

I have been analyzing a DB that is running in Azure SQL that is performing VERY badly. it is on the premium tier with 1750 DTUs available, and at times can still max out DTUs.

Ive identified a variety of querys and terrible data access patterns thru stored procs, which has reduced load.  But there is still this massive disparity between DTU and CPU usage in the image below, any other image i see of the "Query Performance Insight" in azure sql shows the DTU line aligning with the CPU usage for the most part.

[DTU (in red) to CPU usage per query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EWZq.png)

Looking at the C# app sitting ontop of this, for each user that uses the app, it creates a SQL user, and uses that user in the connection string to access the DB.  This means that connection pooling is not being used, resulting in a massively larger number of active users/sessions on the SQL azure DB.  Could this be the sole reason why there is such high DTU usage?

Or could i possibly be missing something regarding IO that isnt visible in the Azure portal?

Thanks
Neil

EDIT:  Adding sessions and workers image!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMwj2.png)

Based on that im not convinved now..  what is the session percentage of?  Like its 10% but 10% of what?  the max allowed?

Edit2:  Adding more metrics:

One week:
[image]

2-3 hours when load is high:
[image]

The purple spike i believe is the reindex so can ignore that!

Comment: Look at what is taking the most CPU time in Query Store.

Comment: Yeah i done that, but as you can see from the pic i attached, the CPU usage for the top 20 queries only uses about 5-10%, you will see that the DTU usage is always about 30% higher and sometimes it spikes to close to 100% DTU usage!! other DB's the DTU and CPU usually track eachother like this https://acom.azurecomcdn.net/80C57D/cdn/mediahandler/docarticles/dpsmedia-prod/azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-query-performance/20160817102412/performance.png

Comment: Query Id 122 is using 61.5% ! Add those top 5 together, and you almost hit 85% I would definitely see if you can improve 122. Post a query plan if possible.

Comment: that was an example i gave you to show how DTU is closely mapped the CPU usage ... see my original post with the actual screenshot of the performance graph.

Comment: anyone?  ............

Comment: Could you please check if you C# application and the database are hosted in the same location? if they are hosted in different location, there could be latencies.

Comment: no it isnt latency that is causing the issue, i dont believe it would manifest like this anyway.

Comment: ok, so looking at your whole week view, it would appear that you are CPU bound. What I mean is, your DTU and CPU percentages are the same. So when you are under load I would pay attention to how much CPU you are using at those times.  If there is any way to reduce CPU during those peaks, you will see better performance from SQL.

Comment: Now, Looking at just the peak 2-3 hour period, while the purple is spiking on the graph at over 80% per the line chart, the percents at the bottom don't agree. The graph shows > 80% of your LogIO is used, yet the details show 1%.  I think you may need to zoom in closer on that ~8am period to see if you are Log IO bound. Also you need to reconsider re-indexing unless you have a GREAT reason to do so in SQL PaaS, it's not necessary under most conditions, and most of the time just costs DTUs.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to understand DTU versus resources was a stumbling block for me too.  Click on your Resource utilization chart and click Edit[image: default resource chart]

Then you get a slider with a lot of resources you can monitor. Select Sessions, and Workers percent.  More than likely one of these are your problems.  If not, you can add in: CPU, Data IO, Log IO, and/or In-memory OLTP percentage. Hit OK.

[image: Resource options]

Now, what you should find is the real cost in your query or queries.  Learning how your queries consume the different resources can help you fix performance problems like these.  I learned this when doing large inserts, I was maxing out my Log IO, and everything else was <5% utilization.

Try that, and if you are right about connection pooling, unfortunately that will mean some refactoring in the application. At the very least, using this will give you more insight than just looking at that DTU percentage!

Comment: ive added that image to my original answer, does that look in any way incorrect to you?  I guess the workers are slightly high/

Comment: Your workers and sessions aren't as high as I would have expected given your original symptoms. Can you collect another image with the other percentages (CPU, Data IO and Log IO) just around one of those peak periods? One of them should be nearly 93.23% based on that last image. Once you find the highest resource, we have a way to troubleshoot further!

Comment: ok.. ive found that the peak around 90% is reindexing happening once a day!!

Comment: it doesnt explain such high load i believe around 30 pc on the MAX azure sql instance i can get!!

Comment: OK, re-indexing shouldn't be necessary since you aren't in a traditional SQL Instance here. You can't think about disc access in quite the same way.  Are queries slowing down significantly, and that's why you're rebuilding the indexes? Are you checking the fragmentation levels before rebuilding to see if a reorganization would be a better option?

Comment: Also, can you capture one more graph just around that re-indexing operation, maybe 1 hour on either side of the peak, but include all the percentages (DTU, CPU, both IOs, sessions, and workers)  Once we drill in, I think we can get a better look. The percentages can change a little when you look at 2-3 hours instead of 2-3 days. Trust me, it's confusing. Some times I pull the dmvs out to excel to get a better look.

Comment: Thanks for the input, ive uploaded a full week with all the percentages you requested, and also one for 3 hours.  thanks again!!